# Wordpress Logout Issue - Plugin conflict leading to white screen of death

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, content-management-system

I have a plugin in my website "WP Events Manager" in my theme "Eduma" by "Thimpress" which was causing a WordPress logout issue. After debugging I came to know that after deactivating the plugin the logout functionality works fine, But the major problem deactivating is that the data associated with the plugin is powering the maximum parts of the website. Right Now the status of the plugin is active.

Website URL : http://webmateinfo.net/demo/HTML/

Regarding this issue the following process i've tried and came so far :-

1. I've tried with the wordpress logout functions but non of them came up with a different solution.
2. I tried to redirect the logout action to another page but no redirections are working either
3. Deactivating all the plugins related to custom logout functions but that wasn't causing the issue.
4. Only after deactivating this plugin the logout functionality works fine.

The website is getting logged out but instead of redirecting the screen ends with a white screen of death with URL : http://webmateinfo.net/demo/HTML/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=aafafd9dea

Comment: can you enable debug mode so it will display the error?

Comment: Yes sure ... hold on a sec ..

Comment: yes @jinesh i've indeed.

Comment: ok I am waiting

Comment: i've already enabled the debug mode @jinesh

Comment: okay let me check

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is coming almost 3 years late but the simple way to do this is to go to settings of WP Events Manager > Pages Tab, and use the same pages you use for your website, hence it inherits the same user registration settings of the main website. For example my WP Events Manager Pages settings are below:

1. Register Page: Register (the same default register page from Eduma)

2.Login Page:   Log In (the same default login page from Eduma)

3. Forgot Password: My account (it will use the websites core Account page to do this)
4. Reset Password: My account
5. My Account: My account